# Is there any historical origins for the masks in Noragami?

Tags: culture, noragami

In *Noragami*, some characters wear masks (e.g. Rabo).

[image: Rabo's mask]

I know what they are and everything, but I feel like I've seen something like it before, but I can't find anything online (Rabo's mask especially).

Are the masks completely fictional, or are they based off of anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the one eyed mask in Noragami?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27133/what-is-the-one-eyed-mask-in-noragami)

Comment: @JustPlain I'm not sure this is a dupe of that question. The OP has already mentioned that they "know what they are and everything", which I assume in-universally, but the question seems looking for out-of-universe explanation.

Comment: On the other hand, it might be related to *Noh masks*, as explained on [a possibly related question on different series (*Natsume's Book of Friends*)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/20337/2516), but I haven't researched further for *Noragami*.

Comment: @Aki Tanaka You might be right. While reading for the first time I thought OP was looking for the meaning of the mask but after reading your comment that is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Using an eye is a common mask design. Maybe that's why it feels familiar to you.

[image] [2011] Mirai Nikki

[image] [2008] Soul Eater

[image] [1999] 20 Seiki Shounen

[image] [1998-2000] Zelda for N64

[image] [1995] On Your Mark

[image] [1990] Fushigi no Umi no Nadia

The ones wearing a piece of cloth to hide their face are usually unimportant background characters, though. If I remember correctly the purpose is to prevent servants from seeing the face of the emperor. Or sometimes it is people dressed completely in black with a black cloth mask who are doing background tasks and are supposed to be treated as not being there, for example during a performance.